# Flutter Firestore not respond when get documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Thank you, problem is solved.
maybe anyone want this.

```
    Future<void> startAway(String awayID) async {
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _categoryCollectionReferance
    .doc(awayID)
    .collection("joiners")
    .get();

final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()["uid"]).toList();

print(allData);}
```

Comment: Try replacing 1) `.map((query) { ... })` with `.map((query) { ... }).toList()` (since `snapshots()` return a Stream) and 2) the first `return` with `return await` (since `startAway` returns a Future).

Comment: i got this error; type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: You got this error in which line?